# Spring returns success but ajax call goes to error

Tags: jquery, spring

```
   $.ajax({
                        type: "PUT",
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        // dataType: 'json',
                        url: "/change-password",
                        data: stringifiedDTO,
                        success: function (data) {

console.log("SUCCESS : ");

  },
                        error: function (e) {      console.log("errror : ");

          }
                    });
                };
```

I am calling this query. I am sure this goes to backend because I can see `Success` in network tab which is coming from backend

```
@PutMapping(value = {"/change-password"},
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<String> changePassword(@RequestBody PasswordChangeDTO dto
    , HttpServletResponse response
    ) {

        boolean isChanged = service.changePassword(dto);

        if(isChanged) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Success!");
        }

        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Error");

    }
```

But in the console of browser , i see

```
JSON stringifiedDTO passwordChangeDTO: {"newPassword":"51","newPasswordConfirm":"51","userId":"3"}errror :
```

Why it goes to error?